# How to document a wrapped response to be displayed in swagger ui using a Swashbuckle in asp.net core web api

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I working on a `ASP.NET Core 3.1` web api project. I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0` for documenting my API. Things are working good. However I got stuck with generating response types as my api is using an middleware to wrap every response for consistency. I'm not able to generate correct response type in my swagger ui.

Here is an simple example,

**My Action Method:**

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>))]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
...
```

As I mentioned, the project has response middleware which will wrap all the response as shown in the below format,

```
{  
    "Version": "1.0.0.0",  
    "StatusCode": 200,  
    "Message": "Request successful.",  
    "Result": [  
        "value1",  
        "value2"  
    ]  
}
```

Because of this I'm getting mismatch in response value in my swagger ui.

Example of response schema shown in swagger ui as per `[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>))]`

[image]

But the actual wrapped response looks like,

[image]

Is it possible to handle these wrapped response using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0`. Please assist me.

Comment: That is one strange middleware, I get a feeling that should all be on response header not on the body

Comment: Yeah I understand and agree. I joined a project recently where they have such project in production and they don't want to break the contract. Hence I'm doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some analysis and research, I found the solution. It's pretty simple using the `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute.

I created a separate `class` named `ResponseWrapper<T>`,

```cs
public class ResponseWrapper<T>
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

And then decorated my action method as follows,

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(ResponseWrapper<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>))]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
...
```

And that works. Hope this helps someone.