# Swagger c# ProduceResponseType for Wrapped AutoWrapper Response

Tags: c#, swashbuckle

As all of our responses are wrapped in AutoWrapper,

what is the best way to tell swagger that they are wrapped by AutoWrapper ?

Instead of adding this on every controller methods ?

```
[ProducesResponseType( 200, Type = typeof( AutoWrapper<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> ) )]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize your effort and create your own [API Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-web-api-conventions) and apply it to your assembly in Startup.cs.

Test model:

```
public class MyTestModel
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public int SomeInteger { get; set; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}
```

Response Wrapper (inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656791/how-to-document-a-wrapped-response-to-be-displayed-in-swagger-ui-using-a-swashbu)):

```
public class AutoWrapper<T>
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

Convention Class:

```
public static class MyAppConventions
{
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(AutoWrapper<List<MyTestModel>>))]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Suffix)]
    public static void Weather()
    {
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<MyTestModel> GetWeather()
{
    List<MyTestModel> models = new List<MyTestModel>
    {
        new MyTestModel
        {
            SomeString = "Hello world!",
            SomeInteger = 101,
            SomeBool = true
        }
    };

    return models;
}
```

Lastly, in the Startup, you need to add a decorator:

```
[assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(MyAppConventions))]
namespace NameSpace
{
    public class Startup
    {
      //stuff...
    }
}
```

In Swagger, this will get illustrated as:

[image: Swagger]

[image: Schema view]

This approach however some-what relies on a naming standard being established across your controller method names in order to minimize the amount of code you'll need to write in the Convention class.  You can use the [`ApiConventionNameMatch` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-requirements) to match on a suffix, prefix, any method name (ignores parameters), and exact name (parameter or method must match). For example, you can cover all of your controller methods in your project that are named `Get(int id)` by declaring the following in the convention class:

```
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(AutoWrapper<YourObject>))]
[ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
public static void Get(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: If there are several methods in the WeatherController, eg. GetWeather1 returning List<Model1> and GetWeather2 returning List<Model2>, is there an easy way to make the convention generic ?

Comment: @Porton I did try to make it more generic, but had some issues. I think I might have an idea on how to make it more generic, but I'll have to experimemt some. Although, I *think* using `ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any` should do trick for your scenario. You would use that name matching behavior on a `public static void GetWeather` declaration I believe. I'll have to check back tomorrow with seeing if I can make this more.generic though.

Comment: Actually, the name matching of Any won't work I believe, since what you need in your case is a way to generalize the `Type` that is produced.

Answer (score 3):

This Swagger IOperationFilter does the trick for me, it creates an AutoWrapper type for each Operation.

```
public class ResponseWrapperOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply ( OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context )
    {
        //eg. IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>
        var responseType = context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes[0].Type;

        //eg. AutoWrapper<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>
        var wrappedResponseType = typeof( AutoWrapperDefinition<> ).MakeGenericType( responseType );

        //new schema, TODO is to check if schema exists
        var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(
            wrappedResponseType,
            context.SchemaRepository
            );

        var openApiResponse = new OpenApiResponse
        {
            Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>()
            {
                ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType()
                {
                    Schema = schema
                }
            },
        };
        operation.Responses.Clear();
        operation.Responses.Add( "200", openApiResponse );
        //TODO: add Response for other status code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the following improvements to Lydon Ch answer:

- Check for existing schema before creating
- Only remove the 200 response instead of all responses:

```
public class ResponseWrapperOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply ( OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context )
    {
        //eg. IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>
        var responseType = context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes[0].Type;

        //eg. AutoWrapper<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>
        var wrappedResponseType = typeof( AutoWrapperDefinition<> ).MakeGenericType( responseType );

        //Added - To Check for existing Schema first
        context.SchemaRepository.TryLookupByType(wrappedResponseType, out var schema );

        if(schema == null)
        {
            schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(
                wrappedResponseType,
                context.SchemaRepository
            );
        }

        var openApiResponse = new OpenApiResponse
        {
            Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>()
            {
                ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType()
                {
                    Schema = schema
                }
            },
        };

        operation.Responses.Remove(StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString());
        operation.Responses.Add(StatusCodes.Status200OK.ToString(), openApiResponse);
    }
}
```